# Use one table to update another SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have having problems updating one table from another. I want SQL to update the rows in `Employees` from the data in `CompanyEmployees` where the two `EmployeeNum` fields are the same. Also if an `EmployeeNum` exists inside of `CompanyEmployees` that doesn't match one in `Employees` then I need a new row created in `Employees`
I so far have tried a join for the two tables.

```
SELECT Employees.PhoneNum, Employees.Data, 
       CompanyEmployees.PhoneNum, CompanyEmployees.SystemData 
FROM CompanyEmployees 
INNER JOIN Employees 
ON CompanyEmployees.Employees=Techs.EmployeeNum
```

I get the right column data in both tables but i doesnt update `Employees`. Do I need an INSERT or UPDATE somewhere?
How can I insert the whole row of data from `CompanyEmployees` into `Employees` where `CompanyEmployees.EmployeeNum` doesn't exist in `Employees`?

I need to do this because `CompanyEmployees` is only a phone directory and `Employees` has phone numbers and more information. But `CompanyEmployees` has new hires inside it that are not inside `Employees`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember RDBMS has the R for relational. They are built for relationships.
To update you Employees table with the CompanyEmployees table you could use something like the below:

```
INSERT INTO Employees (columns) VALUES (SELECT columns FROM CompanyEmployees) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

You probably do not even need 'Employees' as it is a superset of 'CompanyEmployees'. I would suggest looking to merge the two tables or at least move the data into a single table.

Comment: ah great did not think about nested sql and did not know about 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'..thanks alot